# Decimal Floating Point to Shortest Binary

Tags: computer-science, binary, floating-point

Might be more of a Comp Sci question so apologies if it's not appropriate.

Basically I have a range bounded by two floating-point decimals <1. I need to find a short binary number lying between them.

For example: [.665811575, .6658289)

My method is to choose the shortest *decimal* number in the interval (.66582) and apply the following algorithm:

```
If >=0.5 write down "1" and subtract 0.5
Else if < 0.5 write down "0"
Multiply by 2
Repeat until number is 0.0
```

This works however the shortest decimal leads to quite a long binary number. A script I wrote spat out a 53 bit binary number. This is an exam question so I don't have time to do 53 iterations of the algorithm.

Does anyone know how I can pick a better number from the range which will lead to a shorter binary number? Or maybe you have a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you convert each endpoint to binary in parallel.  After each step, see if your two binary numbers disagree; if they do then you're almost done.

Comment: I'd imagine this would work too but it's a bit more effort when in an exam situation. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, your method is near what I'd suggest.

> If > 1, write '1' subtract 1, else write 0
>
> Multiply by 2

You want accuracy to 1 in 100000, or 2^17 (131,072) so I believe 17 digits after decimal should do it. It may very well be an infinite non-repeating series, so I'd quit after either X iterations (the 17 I suggest) or until the a less than x less than b is favorable. The '0' may never occur.

Note to readers, it's been a long time since I've written any code. An edit would be appreciated, as I think this is pretty close.

It turns out 18 is correct for this question, (please verify)

.101010100111001011

equals

0.665813446044921875

which is between .665811 and .665828

Comment: So following this method can I just stop after 17 bits (or whatever power of two provides enough accuracy)? I don't have to keep going until I end up with 0 or anything?

Comment: I believe so. Perhaps 18. Because 1/(2^17) should get you greater accuracy than the difference of the two number you pose. Zero may never happen.

Comment: I just tested it out. Stopping after 17 iterations works perfectly but I'll do an extra one in the exam to be safe. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @carlmango11 - Glad to help. I loved this stuff back in school.

Answer (score 1):

`a=.665811575; b=.6658289`

`print "0."`

`while (b<=.5 or a>.5) {`

`if (b<=.5) { print "0"; a=2*a; b=2*b; }`

`else { print "1"; a=2*a-1; b=2*b-1; }`

`}`

`print "1"`

Comment: I see how this works, but when does it terminate?